# spark posexplode fails in with column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I use posexplode in sparks `withColumn` statement?

```
Seq(Array(1,2,3)).toDF.select(col("*"), posexplode(col("value")) as Seq("position", "value")).show
```

works just fine, whereas:

```
Seq(Array(1,2,3)).toDF.withColumn("foo", posexplode(col("value"))).show
```

fails with:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: The number of aliases supplied in the AS clause does not match the number of columns output by the UDTF expected 2 aliases but got foo ;
```

Comment: you are missing a `position` alias..you only have `value` specified..either specify both (position and value) or none.

Comment: Obviously. However, `def posexplode(e: Column)` the function signature of the SQL DSL does not allow to add a second column! Is this a bug in the SQL DSL? Note, I am using spark 2.2.2

Comment: It has nothing to do with `posexplode` signature. `withColumn` is simply designed to work only with functions which create a single column, which is obviously not the case here.

Comment: Ok. SO if I try to call it in SELECT using a dynamic construct like: `grouped.select(df.filter(!_.equals("<<myarraycolumn>>")).map(col).:_*), posExplode("<<myarraycolumn>>")` it also fails as no other stuff is allowed before or after the `_:*` operator. And the types (`col`) do not match, so I cannot concatenate the sequences.

Comment: The issue is tracked by this JIRA ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20174, last comment provides a workaround: `df selectExpr("*", "posexplode(s) as (p,c)") drop("s")`

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `withColumn()`, you can select all the columns in the dataframe and append the result of `posexplode()`, including an alias for the `pos` and `col` fields. Here is an example using PySpark.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(["a"], ), (["b", "c"], ), (["d", "e", "f"], )],
    ["A"],
)

df.show()
# +---------+
# |        A|
# +---------+
# |      [a]|
# |   [b, c]|
# |[d, e, f]|
# +---------+

df = df.select("*", F.posexplode("A").alias("B", "C"))
df.show()
# +---------+---+---+
# |        A|  B|  C|
# +---------+---+---+
# |      [a]|  0|  a|
# |   [b, c]|  0|  b|
# |   [b, c]|  1|  c|
# |[d, e, f]|  0|  d|
# |[d, e, f]|  1|  e|
# |[d, e, f]|  2|  f|
# +---------+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this really what you want but you can try select statement instead of withColumn, like

```
df.select('col1', 'col2', F.posexplode('col_to_be_exploded'))
```

Comment: Indeed, I am currently using something similar as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

`withColumn` function doesn't seem to work with `posexplode`. You can use something like this instead:

```
df.select($"*", posexplode($"value").as(List("index", "column")))
```